# Recursive function in R of a sequence

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a function that takes X and n, and returns element Xn. X is a vector of the first 3 elements of the sequence and n is a positive integer.
Xn = Xn-1 + Xn-2 - Xn-3

I am not sure how to outline a function like this in R. Can someone outline the creation of a recursive function for the above numerical sequence?

I have been working with something like this:

```
myfunc <- function(x,n){
  if (n<0){
    print("please enter positive integer")
  } else {
    return(myfunc(n-1 + n-2 + n-3))
  }
}
myfunc (x = c(1, 2, 3), n = 3) #should return 3 (third number in sequence)
myfunc (x = c(1, 2, 3), n = 4) #should return 6
```

Comment: Why recursive? The naive recursive solution rapidly becomes infeasible. Just use a loop to populate a vector.

Comment: Is X[n-1] from the original X or is X[n-1] updated and then that updated value used in the calculation of X[n]?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck X[n-1] would need to be updated

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a recursive function, but it will give you what you want:

```
myfunc <- function(x, n) sum(x[n - 1:n])

myfunc(1:3, 3) # 3
myfunc(1:3, 4) # 6
```